# Creating a new view in BigQuery, with case statements

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new view in BigQuery using some of the Google hosted data.
The data is for traffic collisions in New York.

For each unique day in the dataset, I want to find the borough and sum up some fields (people injured, killed, etc.)

Now, the dataset does have a borough field, but this is incomplete, and what I have seen is that there are also latitude and longitude fields.  However these are also not complete.
So I see 3 scenarios.

1. The borough is set, use that
2. No borough, but there is lat and long, so use those in a sub query.
3. There is no lat, long or borough, so just enter an "unknown" here

to find the borough from lat and long, there is another public dataset, and I used this with a lat and long to check

```sql
SELECT UPPER(tz_loc.borough) FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_loc
WHERE (ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, ST_GeogPoint(-73.94398, 40.680088),0))
```

and that seemed to work.

So I constructed my query like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `your-project-id.your_dataset_id.collisions_data_bourgh` AS
SELECT CAST(timestamp as DATE) as collision_date, 
COUNT(CAST(timestamp as DATE)) as NUM_COLLISIONS, 
CASE 
    WHEN ds.borough IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(borough as STRING) -- when the borough is set
    WHEN ((ds.latitude IS NOT NULL or ds.longitude IS NOT NULL) AND ds.borough IS NULL) THEN (SELECT CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough)as STRING) FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` tz_loc WHERE (ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, ST_GeogPoint(CAST(ds.longitude AS FLOAT64), CAST(ds.latitude AS FLOAT64)),0))) -- when the borough is null and either lat or long is not null
    WHEN (ds.latitude IS NULL OR ds.longitude IS NULL OR ds.borough IS NULL) THEN "Unknown"
END AS NEIGHBORHOOD,
SUM(CAST(number_of_cyclist_killed as INT64)) as CYCLISTS_KILLED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_cyclist_injured as INT64)) as CYCLISTS_INJURED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_motorist_killed as INT64)) as MOTORISTS_KILLED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_motorist_injured as INT64)) as MOTORISTS_INJURED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_pedestrians_killed as INT64)) as PEDS_KILLED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_pedestrians_injured as INT64)) as PEDS_INJURED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_persons_killed as INT64)) as PERSONS_KILLED,
SUM(CAST(number_of_persons_injured as INT64)) as PERSONS_INJURED,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_mv_collisions.nypd_mv_collisions` ds
GROUP BY collision_date, NEIGHBORHOOD;
```

And the query ran ok - however when I try to query the created view, I get an error
**LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.**

I cannot see where my error is, if it's in the logic, if it's in the way I've joined together things.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter the LEFT OUTER JOIN error since you were not able to the two tables. You can join them in the WHERE clause of your subquery. Adding `AND tz_loc.borough = ds.borough` at your subquery should make it work.

**See working query:**

```
  CREATE VIEW `your-project-id.your_dataset_id.collisions_data_bourgh` AS
  SELECT
  CAST(timestamp AS DATE) AS collision_date,
  COUNT(CAST(timestamp AS DATE)) AS NUM_COLLISIONS,
  CASE
    WHEN ds.borough IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(borough AS STRING) -- when the borough is set
    WHEN ((ds.latitude IS NOT NULL or ds.longitude IS NOT NULL) AND ds.borough IS NULL)
      THEN (
            SELECT CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough)as STRING)
                  FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom tz_loc
                    WHERE 
                        ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, 
                            ST_GeogPoint(CAST(ds.longitude AS FLOAT64), 
                                CAST(ds.latitude AS FLOAT64)),0) 
                                AND tz_loc.borough = ds.borough
            ) 
    WHEN (ds.latitude IS NULL
    OR ds.longitude IS NULL
    OR ds.borough IS NULL) THEN "Unknown"
END
  AS NEIGHBORHOOD,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_cyclist_killed AS INT64)) AS CYCLISTS_KILLED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_cyclist_injured AS INT64)) AS CYCLISTS_INJURED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_motorist_killed AS INT64)) AS MOTORISTS_KILLED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_motorist_injured AS INT64)) AS MOTORISTS_INJURED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_pedestrians_killed AS INT64)) AS PEDS_KILLED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_pedestrians_injured AS INT64)) AS PEDS_INJURED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_persons_killed AS INT64)) AS PERSONS_KILLED,
  SUM(CAST(number_of_persons_injured AS INT64)) AS PERSONS_INJURED,
FROM
  bigquery-public-data.new_york_mv_collisions.nypd_mv_collisions ds 
GROUP BY
  collision_date,
  NEIGHBORHOOD
```

**Snippet of the whole SELECT clause:**

[image]

**Created View:**
[image]

Comment: thanks, that certainly fixed the error. 
However, it seems my query is somehow wrong, I am still getting null neighbourhoods.  I've checked the data and it looks like the conditions are correct (though they were incorrect in my oroginal query) - I added a concat onto the second WHEN block, and nothing is getting selected from that

Comment: To test out, I picked a date - "2021-05-07", I modifed the CASE to the second clause had ```SELECT CONCAT('XX ', CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough) as STRING))```

Comment: I also have 94 nulls, which is all the borough = null rows

Comment: I made the second WHEN block simpler

```WHEN (ds.borough IS NULL AND ds.location IS NOT NULL )
      THEN (
            SELECT CONCAT('XX ', CAST(UPPER(tz_loc.borough) as STRING))
                  FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom tz_loc
                    WHERE 
                        ST_DWithin(tz_loc.zone_geom, 
                            ST_GeogPoint(CAST(ds.longitude AS FLOAT64), 
                                CAST(ds.latitude AS FLOAT64)),0) 
                                AND tz_loc.borough = ds.borough
            ) ```

Comment: Apologies, I can't get the formatting working correctly

Comment: Somehow the error exists in the select in the second WHERE block.
If I replace the Select with a constant, then that seems to work.

Comment: @Ricci D - the ANd tz_loc.borough = ds.borough , that is in a block where the ds will be null - the tz won't be null, would that be an issue?

Comment: @Joseph it might be better to create a new question about problem in the query logic since the original question is already answered. Creating a new question will also open an opportunity for the community to contribute :)

Comment: I'll add this into a new question - while the answer sort of works (well it works based on the question, my question was wrong.. )

Comment: Hi @Joseph, if you find the answer helpful, consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, then feel free to accept it.

Comment: Hi @Dondi - the answer got rid of an error, but didn't get me what I needed - so trying to pick apart it to find how it works / fix it